# How to run executable file from packaged Electron app

Tags: node.js, electron, executable, child-process, electron-builder

I am building an app with Electron in which there are some executables which run just fine when running `npm start` from terminal using the child-process in Javascript. However when packaging it with electron-builder my app just cannot find the executables. I have read many related posts and none answer my question.

The solution here https://github.com/sindresorhus/fix-path does not resolve my issue.

Here is my code

```
function updateCourses(platform){
const fixPath = require('fix-path');

alert(process.env.PATH);

fixPath(); //This is the package but does not resolve my issue

alert(process.env.PATH);

const path=require('path');
var fs = require("fs");
var mysql=require("mysql");
// /Applications/mooc-platform.app/
alert(__dirname);
const { exec } = require('child_process');
var run="./../../Users/thanasis/Desktop/mooc-platform\ Mac/scrape_"+String(platform);
exec(run,(error, stdout, stderr) => {
if (error) {
    alert(`exec error: ${error}`);
        alert(`Something wrong happened: ${stdout}`);
        alert(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    return;
}
    else{
        alert(platform+" courses downloaded");
        alert("Updating database");

      var con=mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "simple1234",
        database: "moocs"
      });

        var v=false;
        con.connect(function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected!");


            platform=String(platform);
            var num = fs.readFileSync("../../Users/thanasis/Desktop/mooc-platform\ Mac/courses/"+platform+"/numofcourses.txt");
            num=parseInt(num,10);
            let plat=platform;
            for(i=0; i<num; i++){
                pth="../../Users/thanasis/Desktop/mooc-platform\ Mac/courses/"+platform+"/course"+i.toString()+".json";
                var content = fs.readFileSync(pth);
                var object = JSON.parse(content);
                String.prototype.setCharAt = function(index,chr) {
                    if(index > this.length-1) return str;
                    return this.substr(0,index) + chr + this.substr(index+1);
                }
                var ti=String(object.title);
                ti=ti.replace(/'/g,'i');
                sql="INSERT INTO courses (name) VALUES('"+ti+"') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=0";
                con.query(sql,function(err,result){
              if(err) throw err;
              console.log(result);
            });
                // con.query('DELETE FROM courses',function(err,result){
            //   if(err) throw(err);
            //   console.log(result);
            // });
            }
            v=true;
            con.end(function(err,result){
                if(err) throw err;
                if(!alert("Updated")){
                    window.location.href="load_courses.html";
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

}

Optimally this would run from the applications folder (in Macos) with no issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are packaging your app as asar:

All your paths are relative to your file. So the moment this file changes its location the path won't work anymore.

Packing with asar changes

`C:\myApp\scripts\main.js`

to

`C:\myApp\resources\myAppName.asar\scripts\main.js`

so your files cannot be found from there.

There are a couple of options. For example:

- Putting all of your executables and text files inside the asar.
  Upside: you can distribute them with your app. Downside: App might
  get big and this will not work with all executable files, as some may
  need dependencies on their own.
- Determine somehow an absolute path on the current machine (I have no
  idea of macOS. On Windows I read the registry and extract the path I
  need from there.)
- Provide different paths if packed or not via e.g.
  `electron-is-running-in-asar`package.